# ERROR: function does not exist when creating a PostgreSQL aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL aggregate function that calculates the average salary of employees:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION salary_sum(numeric, numeric)
RETURNS numeric
AS $$
SELECT $1 + $2;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avg_final_func(numeric[])
RETURNS numeric
AS $$
SELECT AVG(u)
FROM unnest($1) AS x(u);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE AGGREGATE avg_salary(numeric) (
  SFUNC = salary_sum,
  STYPE = numeric,
  FINALFUNC = avg_final_func,
  INITCOND = '0'
);
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: function avg_final_func(numeric) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error, since I've defined the avg_final_func function in the code above. I've also tried changing the function name and redefining it, but I still get the same error.

Can anyone help me understand what's causing this error and how to fix it? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: It's a typo, [ and ] are missing: numeric vs numeric[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you trying to build an example User Aggregate function not just avoiding `avg()`. (Or is this a homework/tutorial exercise?) However your code shows a couple conceptual mistakes.

- Your final function (avg_final_func) expects an numeric array input.
  Therefore your state-to-state transition function must produce
  numeric array, not as you have a scalar quantity.
- State Type (stype) must be compatible with state-to-state and final
  function parameter type, so must also be a numeric array,
- The initial condition (initcond) must initialize a structure
  compatible with the state-to-state parameter, so must also be a
  numeric array.
  Taken all together arriving at: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fEoa7lRJ))

```
    create or replace function salary_sum(numeric[], numeric)
      returns numeric[]
     language sql
    as $$
       select array_append ($1 , $2);
    $$; 
    
    create or replace function avg_final_func(numeric[])
      returns numeric
     language sql  
    as $$
       select avg(u)
         from unnest($1) as x(u);
    $$;
    
    create aggregate avg_salary(numeric) (
      sfunc = salary_sum,
      stype = numeric[],
      finalfunc = avg_final_func,
      initcond = '{}' 
    );
```

There is however a potential problem with the above. It must build an array containing each value received. Now this is not specifically incorrect especially with only a few tens or hundreds of values, but, I would not want to create an array with 500K or more values. But this is avoidable. Which I think your initial implementation was attempting. The approach is to maintain a array of 2 elements: The sum of the values and the number of values. (also in demo)

```
create or replace function salary_sum2(numeric[], numeric)
  returns numeric[]
 language sql
as $$
  select array[$1[1]+$2,$1[2]+1];

$$;

create or replace function avg_final_func2(numeric[])
  returns numeric
 language sql
as $$
select case when $1[2] != 0
            then $1[1]/$1[2] 
            else null::numeric
       end;
$$;

create aggregate avg_salary2(numeric) (
  sfunc = salary_sum2,
  stype = numeric[],
  finalfunc = avg_final_func2,
  initcond = '{0,0}' 
);
```